# Excel Addin - Could not load file or assembly 'System.Buffers, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, excel-addins, pnp-framework

I have installed PnP.Framework NuGet package to read files from the SharePoint portal in my Excel Addin project (.Net Framework 4.6.1). When I debug my project locally, my Addin related code is working fine. I have bundled the entire deployment files as an executable file by using Visual Studio Setup project (.msi file). After installing the Excel Addin, I am getting below error. I have tried various approaches to resolve this issue. There is no luck still now. Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

**PnP.Framework Version:** 1:13.0

**System.Text.Json Version:** 4.7.2

**Stack Trace:**

> Message: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Buffers,
> Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or
> one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
> does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT:
> 0x80131040) StackTrace:    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(String json, Type
> returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options)    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json,
> JsonSerializerOptions options)    at
> PnP.Framework.Utilities.TokenHelper.GetMetadataDocument(String realm)
> at PnP.Framework.Utilities.TokenHelper.GetStsUrl(String realm)    at
> PnP.Framework.Utilities.TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(String
> targetPrincipalName, String targetHost, String targetRealm)    at
> PnP.Framework.Utilities.ACSTokenGenerator.GetToken(Uri siteUrl)    at
> PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager.b__62_0(String
> site)    at
> PnP.Framework.AuthenticationManager.<>c__DisplayClass78_0.b__0(Object
> sender, WebRequestEventArgs args)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.OnExecutingWebRequest(WebRequestEventArgs
> args)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetWebRequestExecutor()
> at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.d__37.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.d__36.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.d__28.MoveNext()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task)    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
> at
> GoSystem_Extension_Automation.Dialogs.SettingsDialog.d__36.MoveNext()
> Source: System.Text.Json TargetSite: System.Object
> Deserialize(System.String, System.Type,
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions)